# Will BigQuery move records into the right partition?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table that is partitioned by the timestamp contained in column X. However, during ingestion this value might be NULL, and only later on will be filled with an UPDATE.

Will BigQuery move the record to the right partition after the UPDATE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you execute an UPDATE statement and set the partitioning column to have different timestamps, BigQuery will move the associated rows into the appropriate partitions.